# Task list for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, project-planning, tasklist

I often find myself in need of writing down a future Visual Studio solution improvement. Having them at hand while working on personal projects is very handy and accelerating.

Is there an extension (or maybe even a build-in feature) that would allow me to write down future changes to a list, and mark rows as "done" after implementation is finished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can use the "Task List" in Visual Studio:

> Menu *View* → *Task List*

Also, in the code, you can use tokens in your comments, so Visual Studio can auto-populate your task list. Such as:

```
//TODO: xyz
//HACK: ABC
```

The predefined tokens can also be extended:

> Visual Studio → menu *Tools* → *Environment* → *Task List* → *Tokens*

Comment: yes. We can extend the tokens by creating our own. (visual studio → environment → task list → tokens)

Comment: I assume it is VS deployment-wide? And it isn't TFS-integrated, right?

Comment: Its independent of TFS. If you use Predefined Tokens, VS auto-populates the task list on which ever machine the Solution is opened. If you use Custom Tokens, they are picked up by VS in which the Custom Tokens are configured. if you need VS deployment-wide, use predefined tokens!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a [Task List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/170k1bbs.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

It's right in the *View* menu... *View* → *Task List*

The button on the far right side will let you add a new task. Any code comments starting with "TODO" will also appear there automatically.